# When can I use "with" + object + adjective (example: "with him dead")?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, pronouns, at-with

I just watched a movie in which someone more or less says "Oh yeah, **with him dead**, you want me hacking the computer"
My question: to what extent can I use this construction? Is it grammatically right to say "**with them mad at me**, I wanna do it"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a verbless clause as complement to *with* where *with* is followed by subject + predicate, but with no verb in the predicate (CaGEL p1267). It is also possible to use *without* as head of the PP:

*They were wandering around [**without** any clothes on]*

*With* and *without* do not license finite complements, but non-finites are found in addition to verbless forms:

*Without her **realising** it, Fabia's thoughts drifted back to the Gloucestershire home*

*Without anything **said**, Tuathal turned in the saddle and held up a flat palm for silence*

The predicate could be a gerund-participial, a past participial, NP, PP or AdjP.

Comment: What about *with his being dead* instead of *with him dead*?

Comment: @Fadli Sheikh The difference would be between subject + predicative complement, and subject + gerund participial. They are both  allowed in this construction. The meaning is pretty much the same with _being dead_ taking a more internal view of the situation.

Comment: These are all gerunds, though they often delete auxiliary _being_ or _having_. It can be put back again without changing meaning, though: _without having any clothes on, without anything being/having been said_.

Answer (score 0):

with + person or pronoun or object + past participle or adjective or noun is an idiomatic usage.

Merriam Weber says this:
c—used as a function word to indicate *a result attendant on a specified action*
*got off with a light sentence*

Except in the OP's example, there is the addition of a past participle, so I am calling that idiomatic. But all of those uses are about "a result attendant on a specified action".

- With them gone, we could do the work.
- With John's leaving, there was  now a problem.
- With the car stolen, we could not get to work.
- With the house painted, we all felt better.

All those could be stated as **Given that x**:

Given they left
Given that John left
Given that the car was stolen
Given that the house was painted.